# Passing variables into higher order functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope, higher-order-functions

I am Following http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html. I have following piece of code

```
function findEven(number, body) {
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) body(i)
}

function unless(test, then) {
    if(!test) then();
}

findEven(10, function (n) {

    unless(n%2, function (n) {

        console.log(n, 'is even')

    });


});
```

My question is if i pass variable `n` into function `unless` it prints the value '`undefined`' to the console. I dont understand why the function `unless` does not hove the access to its outer scope. Could someone please explain the reason?

Comment: You are overriding "n" in your second anonymous function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here

```
function unless(test, then) {
    if(!test) then();
}
```

And here

```
unless(n%2, function (n) {

    console.log(n, 'is even')

});
```

The `unless` function doesn't pass anything to that callback which takes n, so n is undefined.

probably just remove the `n` from the callback so that it is

```
unless(n%2, function () {

    console.log(n, 'is even')

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is `undefined` because the function `then()` is called without any argument. The problem lays when you define the function passed in to `unless`.
The argument `n` overrides the variable `n` already defined in the closure. Therefore, because `then()` is called without arguments, `n` assumes the value `undefined` and the console prints `undefined`.

To fix the bug, just remove `n` from the arguments:

```
unless(n%2, function () {
        console.log(n, 'is even')

    });
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5tvafuqt/

Answer (score 1):

```
findEven(10, function (n) {
    // remove n as an input param
    unless(n%2, function () {
        console.log(n, 'is even')
    });
});
```

1. You **dont** need `n` inside since you have it as a `closure`.
2. Since you are invoking `then()` **without** any param - `n` is undefined.
3. The outer `n` is overridden with the inner scope `n`.